# What causes “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” error when getting wifi information?

Tags: iphone, wifi, ipod

I'm getting the following error

> Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
>   warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame
>
> warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
>   warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.

My app is to get wifi information

```
libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi",RTLD_LAZY);

open = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Open");
bind = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211BindToInterface");
close = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Close");
scan = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Scan");

open(&airportHandle);

bind(airportHandle, @"en0");
```

When the code reaches `open(&airportHandle)`, I receive the error but I'm not sure because at this line it stops.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone) seems to cover the issue.

Comment: Note that MobileWifi is a private framework, and use of such a framework in a shipping application is a very bad idea.  Apple appears to even be using a static analyzer to weed out private API calls in submitted applications now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors, you are usually trying to send a message to a released object. The **BEST** way to track these down is use [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled).

This works by never actually releasing an object, but by wrapping it up as a "zombie" and setting a flag inside it that says it normally would have been released. This way, if you try to access it again, it still know what it was before you made the error, and with this little bit of information, you can usually backtrack to see what the issue was.

It especially helps in background threads when the Debugger sometimes craps out on any useful information.

**VERY IMPORTANT TO NOTE** however, is that you need to 100% make sure this is only in your debug code and not your distribution code. Because nothing is ever released, your app will leak and leak and leak. To remind me to do this, I put this log in my appdelegate:

```
if(getenv("NSZombieEnabled") || getenv("NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled"))
  NSLog(@"NSZombieEnabled/NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled enabled!");
```

If you need help finding the exact line, Do a Build-and-Debug (CMD-Y) instead of a Build-and-Run (CMD-R). When the app crashes, the debugger will show you exactly which line and in combination with NSZombieEnabled, you should be able to find out exactly why.

Comment: ObjectAllocator Instrument can be configured with zombie enabled. If it finds it, it throws an alert with zombie address and you can see there in the stack backtrace exactly the call that caused the problem (the call with the latest time stamp)

Comment: ZombieEnabled is not fullproof though; that only works for NSObjects.  If the memory that is triggering that is not an actual object (a struct or something else) then NSZombie will not help you.

Answer (score 1):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS always occurs when accessing memory you already have released. In your sample code, I can't see where `airportHandle` is initialized, or wheter it is initialized at all for that matter.

If it has been initialized but you just forgot to post that code, you should try checking if you released the handle somewhere.

To debug such an access violation, it is often useful to set the `NSZombieEnabled` Environment flag to `YES`. This will cause the Obj-C runtime to log access to released memory to the console. You can find a [full tutorial](http://www.corbinstreehouse.com/blog/2007/10/instruments-on-leopard-how-to-debug-those-random-crashes-in-your-cocoa-app/) on how to use that information together with Instruments to find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it EASILY with Instruments: See this really great post:

http://www.corbinstreehouse.com/blog/2007/10/instruments-on-leopard-how-to-debug-those-random-crashes-in-your-cocoa-app/comment-page-1/#comment-43762

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS. is mainly found when u released any object which you have further needed in future.it is unable to find but there is solution to find out u must have to be in a DEBUG mode . then follow these links

http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone

it really works

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same thing, and I get the same issue. If you enter in debug mode, you can see that when we use `open = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Open");` the function still equals to 0.

So in my opinion you are looking for the `Apple80211Open` in a framework which did not contain this function.

`Apple80211Open` is in the `Apple80211` private framework which is outdated in >iOS 2.x SDK. The equivalent in the MobileWifi framework, which is for the 3.x and 4.x SDK, is `/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/WiFiManager.bundle/WiFiManager` instead of `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi`